# How to move the scroll bar of the browser on a pdf file with ASP / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, asp-classic

I am looking for some time if there are free apis / or other projects in order to **move the scroll bar of the browser** to the position of an item referred to a **pdf** document.
I would like to redirect the user to a pdf file of my site ("/ Help.pdf") directly to the **desired position**.(on  a title or page number, for example) and not on position (x or y) as it varies according to the screen resolution.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it passing parameters to the link :

`<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#glossary">` Goes to glossary

`<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=3">` Goes to page 3

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html

Comment: Yess. Thank you this is exactly what I wanted!